# The movement background picture

Tags: java, swing

having a little difficulty. I am writing a small game (trying to write)) of any difficulties. That's the game code:

```
package Game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Board extends JPanel {

    private final String IMAGE_PATH_DOWN1 = "C:\\Users\\дНМ\\workspace\\Game\\image\\Down_Pic1.png";
    private final String IMAGE_PATH_DOWN2 = "C:\\Users\\дНМ\\workspace\\Game\\image\\Down_Pic2.png";

    private final String IMAGE_PATH_RIGHT1 = "C:\\Users\\дНМ\\workspace\\Game\\image\\Right_Pic1.png";
    private final String IMAGE_PATH_RIGHT2 = "C:\\Users\\дНМ\\workspace\\Game\\image\\Right_Pic2.png";

    private final String IMAGE_PATH_TOP1 = "C:\\Users\\дНМ\\workspace\\Game\\image\\Top_Pic1.png";
    private final String IMAGE_PATH_TOP2 = "C:\\Users\\дНМ\\workspace\\Game\\image\\Top_Pic2.png";

    private final String IMAGE_PATH_LEFT = "C:\\Users\\дНМ\\workspace\\Game\\image\\Left_Pic1.png";
    private final String IMAGE_PATH_LEFT2 = "C:\\Users\\дНМ\\workspace\\Game\\image\\Left_Pic2.png";

    private final String IMAGE_PATH_MAP_Z = "C:\\Users\\дНМ\\workspace\\Game\\image\\Map_Z.png";

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Thing thing;
    private Timer repaintTimer;

    private Image imgCs;
    private Image imgMap;
    private static int speed = 3;

    public Board() {
        init();

    }

    private void init() {

        setFocusable(true);
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
        addKeyListener(new KeyHandler());
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        thing = new Thing();

        imgCs = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(IMAGE_PATH_DOWN1);
        imgMap = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(IMAGE_PATH_MAP_Z);

        repaintTimer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                repaint();
            }
        });

        repaintTimer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        int width = imgCs.getWidth(this);
        int height = imgCs.getHeight(this);

        int scale = 4;
        speed = 3;

        int w = scale * width;
        int h = scale * height;

        //MAP START!
        int widthMap = imgMap.getWidth(this);
        int heightMap = imgMap.getHeight(this);
        int scalem = 4;
        int wm = scalem * widthMap;
        int hm = scalem * heightMap;

           for (int s = 0; s < wm * 10; s += wm) {
                for (int i = 0; i < hm * 10; i += hm) {
                    g2d.drawImage(imgMap, thing.getX()+s, thing.getY()+i,(int) wm, (int) hm, this);

                }
            }
        //MAP END

        g2d.drawImage(imgCs, thing.getX() * speed, thing.getY() * speed,
                (int) w, (int) h, this);

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();

    }

    private class KeyHandler extends KeyAdapter {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            thing.pressed(e.getKeyCode());
            // LEFT!!!
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                if ((thing.getX() * speed % 2) == 0) {
                    imgCs = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
                            IMAGE_PATH_LEFT);

                } else {
                    imgCs = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
                            IMAGE_PATH_LEFT2);
                }
            }
            // RIGHT!
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {

                imgCs = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(IMAGE_PATH_RIGHT1);
                if ((thing.getX() * speed % 2) == 0) {
                    imgCs = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
                            IMAGE_PATH_RIGHT1);
                } else {

                    imgCs = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
                            IMAGE_PATH_RIGHT2);
                }
            }
            // DOWN!
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                if ((thing.getY() * speed % 2) == 0) {
                    imgCs = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
                            IMAGE_PATH_DOWN1);

                } else {
                    imgCs = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
                            IMAGE_PATH_DOWN2);

                }

            }
            // UP!
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                if ((thing.getY() * speed % 2) == 0) {

                    imgCs = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
                            IMAGE_PATH_TOP1);

                } else {
                    imgCs = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
                            IMAGE_PATH_TOP2);

                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            //
        }

    }
}
```

Another class

```
package Game;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

class Thing {

    private final int STEP = 3;
    private int x_pos;
    private int y_pos;

    public void pressed(int keyCode) {

        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: {
            x_pos -= STEP;
            break;
        }
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP: {
            y_pos -= STEP;
            break;
        }
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: {
            x_pos += STEP;
            break;
        }
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN: {
            y_pos += STEP;
            break;
        }
        }
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x_pos;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y_pos;
    }

}
```

And another class)

```
package Game;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ThingMove {

    private String NAME = "Title";
    private int WIDTH = 500;
    private int HEIGHT = 470;

    public ThingMove() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame(NAME);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.add(new Board());

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ThingMove();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Laid back, so that the code did not take place.

The code works, the picture shows the hero, but when he moves to the end of the box it goes under it and disappears, I would like that when you're moving image and background moved with her.To the background is not standing still and moving along with a picture of the hero.help to make it

http://pastebin.com/w4kR7FuQ

http://pastebin.com/jKTCbUpY

http://pastebin.com/bPxSrrrR

Comment: Or throw a link where there are similar examples

Comment: Take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050723/java-applet-game-2d-window-scrolling/16052048#16052048) and [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138363/infinite-background-for-game/16138735#16138735)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Won't answer your question but some thoughts:

1. Don't override paint(). Custom painting is done by overriding paintComponent(). Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information.
2. Don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be used with Key Bindings. See [Motion Using the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for more info.
3. Don't read in the image for every event. Images should be read in at the start of the program for better performance.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment... moreso since you actually state you're not answering the question?