# Java Tile Scrolling Issues

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to programming with graphics and I'm attempting to code a side scrolling 2D game. At the moment, I'm trying to figure out how to approach redrawing a scrolling image as it appears in the JFrame. I'm using 8x8 pixel blocks as images. One possible issue I thought about concerns moving a sprite just 1 or 2 pixels and still rendering each image as it appears pixel by pixel on/off of the screen. How do I go about rendering the image/blocks pixel by pixel instead of whole images should the sprite barely move? Any feedback is much appreciated!

Comment: Start by generating a `BufferedImage` which represents a single screen.  Then, as you scroll either shift this base image left or right and update only the area you need to.  This would then become the new "base"

Comment: Are you using any special packages?

Comment: nawazlj, no I'm not using any packages. I haven't started the code yet but my cousin and I have been brainstorming possible problems that may get in our way so we are trying to solve them before getting too in depth with the game. MadProgrammer, thank you so much for your advice. I will give that a try and see if I can work something out to make it happen! :D

Answer (score 0):

This is a **proof of concept** only!  I randomly generate the tiles that get painted, I hope you have some kind of virtual map setup so you know which tiles to paint at any given virtual point!

Basically, what this does, is when the screen is moved left or right, it shifts the "master" image left or right and stitches new tiles onto new edge

My test was using a style sheet of 31x31 cells (don't ask, I just grab it off the net)

This is VERY scaled down example of the output, it was running at 1100x700+

[image: example]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Scroll {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Scroll();
    }

    public Scroll() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage screen;
        private BufferedImage styleSheet;

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                styleSheet = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/StyleSheet.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), "left");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), "right");

            ActionMap am = getActionMap();
            am.put("left", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    stitch(-31);
                }
            });
            am.put("right", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    stitch(31);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void invalidate() {
            screen = null;
            super.invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void stitch(int direction) {
            if (screen == null) {
                prepareScreen();
            }

            Random r = new Random();
            BufferedImage update = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D g2d = update.createGraphics();
            g2d.drawImage(screen, direction, 0, this);
            int gap = direction < 0 ? (direction * -1) : direction;

            int xOffset = 0;
            if (direction < 0) {
                xOffset = getWidth() - gap;
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < gap; x += 31) {
                for (int y = 0; y < getHeight(); y += 31) {
                    xOffset += x;
                    int cellx = 2;
                    int celly = 2;
                    if (r.nextBoolean()) {
                        cellx = 7;
                        celly = 5;
                    }

                    BufferedImage tile = styleSheet.getSubimage((cellx * 33) + 1, (celly * 33) + 1, 31, 31);
                    g2d.drawImage(tile, xOffset, y, this);
                }
            }
            g2d.dispose();

            screen = update;

            repaint();

        }

        protected void prepareScreen() {

            if (screen == null) {
                screen = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            }

            Random r = new Random();
            Graphics2D g2d = screen.createGraphics();
            for (int x = 0; x < getWidth(); x += 31) {
                for (int y = 0; y < getHeight(); y += 31) {

                    int cellx = 2;
                    int celly = 2;
                    if (r.nextBoolean()) {
                        cellx = 7;
                        celly = 5;
                    }

                    BufferedImage tile = styleSheet.getSubimage((cellx * 33) + 1, (celly * 33) + 1, 31, 31);
                    g2d.drawImage(tile, x, y, this);

                }
            }
            g2d.dispose();

        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            if (screen == null) {
                prepareScreen();
            }
            g2d.drawImage(screen, 0, 0, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: When I look at the your generated JFrame window above, the cells are definitely sliding on/off screen but they appear to be skipping. For example, if one cell is moved half-way off screen or just one or two pixels, it pushes the cell back on screen. Do you know of a way to slide a cell on/off screen just one pixel at a time so it flows smoother? I'm looking at this situation from a gamer's perspective so ideally, the terrain I plan on coding soon should slide pixel by pixel smoothly across the screen instead of block by block. Hope this makes sense. Again, thanks for your examples! Much Help!

Comment: Sure, adjust the direction delta

Comment: Another approach would be to pre generate the entire level and simply use BufferedImage.subImage to show only the viewable area, or just offset the world image to only show the viewable area

Comment: That sounds like it would work but I plan on trying to render random terrain made up of small 8x8 blocks/images. Unfortunately, I cant pre generate that:( Nevertheless, I will try adjusting the directional delta.

Comment: You'll need to "pre build" the world, even if it's random, so that if you need to scroll back, you know what you've built ;)

Comment: Oh man this just got even more confusing, ha ha! Any idea how you can pre build a random 2D terrain world?

Comment: You could either create a virtual map, maybe in a 2D array, from which you can determine the type of tile which should be displayed at any given virtual point and translate that between the virtual and real world or you could simply create a single master BufferedImage and either subImage it or offset its world position accordingly

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050723/java-applet-game-2d-window-scrolling/16052048#16052048) and. [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138363/infinite-background-for-game/16138735#16138735)