# Interactive background

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe

I'm designing a game where you get to the edge of the screen the screen will shift to a new panel of the same map similar the first Zelda game. Which method would be more efficient and or effective, having a thread running using repaint() or would using javax.swing.Timer and calling super.paintComponet work better?

Comment: In my opinion, none of the two is a good solution. Use a `javax.swing.Timer` calling `repaint()` inside the `actionPerformed`, not `super.paintComponent()`. But the timer should not be started inside the `paintComponent` method, if that's what you were suggesting.

Comment: Thanks, I've been doing research on the best way and there have been several ways people have brought up.

Comment: But what exactly is the timer for? Are you trying to do an animation for a transition of the panels? Please consider posting a [mcve] for specific help, as at least I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes the Timer is there for animation transitions, I want a scrolling effect. I haven't started the code yet I'm planning it out before I go in blind I haven't worked much with images. All I want is a stationary backgound and as soon as the player collides with the side of the Jframe the world stops and transitions to the next panel.

Comment: Somethingl like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138363/infinite-background-for-game/16138735#16138735) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502526/java-tile-scrolling-issues/24503005#24503005) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050723/java-applet-game-2d-window-scrolling/16052048#16052048)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually for simple animations, you can use `javax.swing.Timer` But it looks like you are into a more complex game. If you continue to use `swing.Timer` and if your execution of the codes are not fast enough, it may affect the painting of your components causing your UI to be irresponsive.

You can construct a game loop and render according to the frame rate you wanted by invoking `Thread.sleep(delay)` via a worker thread remember do not run it in the Event Dispatch Thread, else your UI will also become irresponsive.