# How to animate a map when moving while the entire map consists of all tiles

Tags: java

I have a map, say of size 200x100. That means there are 200x100 different tiles. I have a character, he moves to the right. The map also moves, but it doesn't animate. It simply draws the new location on the map as so:

```
g.drawImage(grass, x, y, 40, 40, null);
```

I want to figure out how I can do an animation of the map sliding along with my character moving. I thought of one solution, where I just simply have one giant picture of the map, but I that would cause me to rewrite the entire structure I have for the game.

Is it possible to do this with a Timer? I imagine the tiles sliding over one by one rather than all at once.

Thanks!

Comment: [For example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502526/java-tile-scrolling-issues/24503005#24503005) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419808/frames-painting-at-different-times/25423804#25423804)

Comment: You need to maintain a basic concept of the "virtual world" (your entire map) and the "real world" (what is displayed).  You need to ascertain, based on the x/y offset and width/height of the "real world", which tiles will be visible.  Then you need to decide how best to update it. Sometimes, you'll want to repaint the entire "real world" view, sometimes, you can get away with shifting the buffer over and painting only those tiles which are new

Comment: I am going over one of the examples now and I'll let you know how it goes thanks :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I got it to work thanks! One question though, how do I know for sure it printed the entire map? I noticed in that I multiply game height by 128, but say I do smaller numbers such as game height by 12 everything is messed up. Could you explain that please :)

Comment: it depends. For example, you could choose an algorithm which paints only full tiles. So the top/left corner must start at `0x0` for the specified tile and you only move the map by increments of a whole tile, this way, you know you can have a full player view. The other approach is to "over paint", where by you calculate the title which would appear at the top/left corner, but paint a row above it and a column before it (if available) and a row below and a column to the right of expected last title, effectively "over painting" beyond the bounds of the player viewable area