# Graphics involving the road in a 2d racing game in java

Tags: java, graphics

I need to make a game project for my Computer Science class in school, and I have made a good amount of progress on the game. What I need help with is how I can "loop" the road and allow the screen to move with the car.

However I have no idea as to where to start or how to put this feature in my code without dramatically changing it.

Here is the first file of the project:

```
 package gameproject;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class CarMovement {

private int dx;
private int dy;
private int x = 635;
private int y = 550;
private int w;
private int h;
private Image moveimage;

public CarMovement() {

    loadImage();
}

private void loadImage() {

    ImageIcon q = new ImageIcon("racecar.png");
    moveimage = q.getImage(); 

    w = moveimage.getWidth(null);
    h = moveimage.getHeight(null);
}

public void move() {

    x += dx;
    y += dy;
}

public int getX() {

    return x;
}

public int getY() {

    return y;
}

public int getWidth() {

    return w;
}

public int getHeight() {

    return h;
}    

public Image getImage() {

    return moveimage;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        dx = -10;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        dx = 10;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
        dy = -10;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
        dy = 10;
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        dx = 0;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        dx = 0;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
        dy = 0;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
        dy = 0;
    }
}
}
```

The second:

```
 package gameproject;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class CarMovement2 extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

private Timer timer;
private CarMovement racecar;
private final int DELAY = 10;

public CarMovement2() {

    initBoard();
}

private void initBoard() {

    addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
    setBackground(Color.black);
setFocusable(true);

    racecar = new CarMovement();

    timer = new Timer(DELAY, this);
    timer.start();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(new Color(0, 204, 0));
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 1100);
    g.fillRect(1525, 0, 400, 1100);
    g.setColor(new Color(102, 102, 102));
    g.fillRect(400, 0, 1125, 1100);
    g.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    g.fillRect(940, 25, 25, 100);
    g.fillRect(940, 325, 25, 100);
    g.fillRect(940, 475, 25, 100);
    g.fillRect(940, 625, 25, 100);
    g.fillRect(940, 775, 25, 100);
    g.fillRect(940, 925, 25, 100);
    g.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    g.fillRect(400, 175, 1125, 100);
    g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));
    g.fillRect(400, 225, 50, 50);
    g.fillRect(450, 175, 50, 50);
    g.fillRect(500, 225, 50, 50);
    g.fillRect(550, 175, 50, 50);
    g.fillRect(600, 225, 50, 50);
    g.fillRect(650, 175, 50, 50);
    g.fillRect(700, 225, 50, 50);
    g.fillRect(750, 175, 50, 50);
    g.fillRect(800, 225, 50, 50);
    g.fillRect(850, 175, 50, 50);
    g.fillRect(900, 225, 50, 50);
    g.fillRect(950, 175, 50, 50);
    g.fillRect(1000, 225, 50, 50);
    g.fillRect(1050, 175, 50, 50);
    g.fillRect(1100, 225, 50, 50);
    g.fillRect(1150, 175, 50, 50);
    g.fillRect(1200, 225, 50, 50);
    g.fillRect(1250, 175, 50, 50);
    g.fillRect(1300, 225, 50, 50);
    g.fillRect(1350, 175, 50, 50);
    g.fillRect(1400, 225, 50, 50);
    g.fillRect(1450, 175, 50, 50);
    g.fillRect(1500, 225, 25, 50);
    g.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    g.fillRect(380, 0, 20, 1100);
    g.fillRect(1525, 0, 20, 1100);
    doDrawing(g);

    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
}

private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2d.drawImage(racecar.getImage(), racecar.getX(), 
        racecar.getY(), this);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    step();
}

private void step() {       
    Rectangle old = new Rectangle(racecar.getX(), racecar.getY(), racecar.getWidth(), racecar.getHeight());

    racecar.move();

    Rectangle now = new Rectangle(racecar.getX(), racecar.getY(), racecar.getWidth(), racecar.getHeight());

    repaint(old);
    repaint(now);
}

private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        racecar.keyReleased(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        racecar.keyPressed(e);
    }
}
}
```

The third:

```
 package gameproject;


import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public final class CarMovement3 extends JFrame {

 public CarMovement3() {

    InitUI();
}

private void InitUI() {

    add(new CarMovement2());

    setTitle("Top Speed Triumph");
    setSize(1900, 1100);
    setResizable(false);

    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        CarMovement3 ex = new CarMovement3();
        ex.setVisible(true);
    });
}


}
```

Comment: Possible [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050723/java-applet-game-2d-window-scrolling/16052048#16052048), another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138363/infinite-background-for-game/16138735#16138735)

Comment: If I were to use the second example and if I were using Graphics for my background instead of an image like in that code, how would I edit the code to be able to do that.

Comment: That would depend greatly on your context, but you might do something like [this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502526/java-tile-scrolling-issues/24503005#24503005) or [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419808/frames-painting-at-different-times/25423804#25423804)

Comment: The first code appears to work better, however I have no idea on how to implement it to my code, since it keeps telling me that non-static variable moveimage can not be referenced in a static context when I try to use my image variable in the code above in the place of the "StyleSheet" variable from the example code. (First example code as in the one that says "this for example")

Comment: It also seems that the frame being painted in the code is separate from the frame I'm painting in my code, and I also have no idea how to combine those.