# Horizontal tiling background

Tags: java, graphics2d, side-scroller

I'm coding for a game and want the background to repeat itself.

```
xOffset = (int) (camera.getX() % WIDTH);

g.drawImage(bgInv, xOffset - WIDTH, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
g.translate(xOffset, 0);
g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
g.translate(-xOffset, 0);
g.drawImage(bgInv, xOffset + WIDTH, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
```

The first `drawImage` draws when the camera's X is negative
and the third when the camera's X is positive.

- bg is the normal background
- bgInv is the background inverted

The problem is that when I'm moving and the `xOffset` goes from `WIDTH` to 0, it seems like there's a "wrap".

[Click here to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ws0H.jpg)

The console is outputting `xOffset`

I know it is because I'm using modulo to get `xOffset` but I didn't figure out a better way...

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: Modulo of negative numbers gives negative numbers. Try `if (xOffset<0) xOffset+=WIDTH;` as the second line.

Comment: @Marco13 xOffsets never gets negative, but also tried to use ur if statement and also changing it to while but doesn't work still

Comment: Maybe this posting will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138363/infinite-background-for-game/16138735#16138735

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, what you want to repeat is a `2 * WIDTH` by `HEIGHT` image, where the left half is the background image and the right half is the same image horizontally inverted.

So what you can do is the following:

```
xOffset = (int) (camera.getX() % (2 * WIDTH));

// draw the background image at x = xOffset - 2 * WIDTH
g.drawImage(bg, xOffset - 2 * WIDTH, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
g.drawImage(bgInv, xOffset - WIDTH, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);

// draw the background image at x = xOffset
g.drawImage(bg, xOffset, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
g.drawImage(bgInv, xOffset + WIDTH, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
```