# Zoom and Pan JPanel with multiple Images drawn on it

Tags: java, swing, affinetransform

I am drawing a tile map, where I draw a different 64x64 pixel image for every tile, and each tile object draws itself.

I also have a player object and zombie objects that also draw themselves. the player and zombie objects have their own affine transform instantiation that modify the g.drawImage I call for each one.

My question is. how would I implement a 'camera' that I can zoom and pan with, to see only the part of the map inside the JPanel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is start with a `BufferedImage` which will act as the final output.

Create it so it's size is `width x scale` and `height x scale`.

Obtain a `Graphics` context from it using `BufferedImage#createGraphics` and set the context's scale accordingly, using `Graphics#scale`.

Then paint the output to this `Graphics` context, don't forget to call `Graphics#dispose` when you're done.

With this `BufferedImage`, render this to the screen.  This gives you the "zoom" functionality.

For the panning, you can take a look at [Java Applet Game 2D Window Scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050723/java-applet-game-2d-window-scrolling/16052048#16052048) for an example.