# How to move the location of the graphic in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

So I'm creating a game using Javax.swing library for my uni coursework.
I have created a window and I have successfully written code to procedurally generate a game map.

However, I am unable to change the focus of the map. What I mean is that the map is always stuck in one corner of the screen. (IE: Location is set to 0,0, hence the Graphics g (the map) is put in that location going outwards.)

I would like to be able to move the "camera" so that different areas of the map can be viewed by the player.

Bellow I have pasted my method that draws the map onto the screen. Could anyone tell me what I could do to have the camera move at runtime. AKA: to shift the map left or right.

I thought of having a Graphics object that will hold the map, and then I'd only draw a subImage of that Graphics object, but considering how the map will be redrawn every frame (For animation purposes) that just means that I'll have even more graphics to redraw.
The map is 6,400 * 6,400 Pixels

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    try {
        for(int x = 0; x < OverworldMap.MAP_X_SIZE; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < OverworldMap.MAP_Y_SIZE; y++){
                for(int layer = 0; layer < OverworldMap.MAP_LAYER_SIZE; layer++) {
                    g.drawImage(OverworldMap.getTileAt(x, y, layer).getSprite(), x * SPRITE_SIZE, y * SPRITE_SIZE, null);

                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LauncherClass.printErrorLog(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Be sure to override the `getPreferredSize()` method when custom painting to a component, in order to suggest a size to the layout manager and `pack()`

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050723/java-applet-game-2d-window-scrolling/16052048#16052048)? You have to distinguish between two concepts, the "virtual" view of the world and the "physical" view of the world. The idea is, you want to overlay the physical "window" onto of the "virtual" view, allowing you to see small sections of it as needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best / easiest way to solve this is to put a JScrollPane around your JPanel, and make the JPanel the size of your image. You don't need to worry about only repainting the right part of your image - Java is pretty smart about only drawing the parts that are on screen. Note that you can show or hide the ScrollBars, but if you hide them you need to add logic to activate scrolling through some other mechanism

Comment: How exactly would I do that? I have tried using JScrollPane before in a couple of other projects and I could never figure out how to set it up in a way that it works. Mainly because I don't understand whether I have to do (new JPane()).add(new JScrollPane()) or (new JScrollPane(new JPane())). When I created a JScrollPane object with a JPane object reference as a parameter and then I tried to add the JScrollPane object to the JPane, my IDE gave a warning saying that that object is already a component of JPane. Now, when I did only one of those, the scroll bars didn't show up.

Comment: See how to use Scroll Panes: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html one thing to highlight is that you must set the size of your JPanel yourself (see Component.setSize(width, height))

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store a Graphics object and use it later.  It is only valid for the duration of the paint method to which it is passed.

You can, however, simply offset your painting:

```
Image sprite = OverworldMap.getTileAt(x, y, layer).getSprite();
g.drawImage(sprite, x * SPRITE_SIZE - playerX, y * SPRITE_SIZE - playerY, this);
```

(Notice that the last argument to drawImage should be `this`.)

Comment: Is it not illegal to have a sprite being drawn at negative (x,y) coordinates?

Comment: It’s not illegal at all.  In fact, the painting system is smart enough to simply ignore any draw methods whose output is completely out of view.