# How to make a bigger screen then as seen

Tags: java

How can I code in Java with JFrame to make the background appear to move when you go near an edge?

An example is Starve.io when the user can go left and continue going left even though you cannot see it on the computer screen.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  If you can provide demo code for what your frame, user, and background are like this will make it easier to give you code that can be quickly adapted to your project.

Comment: The difficult part is getting your head around the concept of "actual" and "virtual" coordinate spaces. You then need to map between the two in order to offset the image a given amount.  [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050723/java-applet-game-2d-window-scrolling/16052048#16052048)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/193GXEd3SN7uZXtK-v3tjQ-komshvV0JpbMt7m6d3_Gk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Here is the link to my program, if you don't have a google account, just tell me and I can figure out another way to show you. Thanks!  My driver class is also on it.